# Converting string into class

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

#### What I do need:

I pass a string that has to set an unmutable object inside an array, but I do not know hot how to make the transition from the string that the user inputs to the object name I need.

#### What I am intending to do:

I am working on a conversational adventure. The key point is to have a function that creates a command prompt so the user can interact with the game. Whenever the user says "go to somewhere", there is another function called "goto" that compares whether the input is included in the exits of the place where the player is; if so, the attribute "place" for the player takes a new place.

#### What I did:

I made a command prompt that actually works*

```
loop do 
        print "\n >>> "
        input = gets.chomp
        sentence = input.split

        case
        when sentence[0] == "inspect"
                $action.inspect(sentence[1])
            when sentence[0] == "go" && sentence[1] == "to"
                $action.goto(sentence[2])
            when sentence[0] == "quit"
                break
            else
                puts "\nNo le entiendo Senor..."
        end
```

And I initialized the objects as I need them (the third attribute goes for the exits):

```
room = Place.new("room", "Room", [newroom], "This is a blank room. You can _inspect_ the -clock- or go to [newroom].", ["this this"])
newroom = Place.new("newroom", "New Room", [room], "This is another blank room. You can _inspect_ the -clock-", ["this this"])
```

Then I made a method inside the action controller that has to compare and set the places properly. (Beware: monster newbie code following. Protect you eyes).

```
def goto(destiny) #trying to translate the commands into variable names
    if (send "#{destiny}").is_in? $player.place.exits
        $player.place = send "#{sentence[2]}"
        puts destiny.description
    else
        puts "I cannot go there."
    end
end
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: "I do not know hot how to make the transition from the string that the user inputs to the object name I need"; therefore, how do I make the transition from the string that the user inputs to the object name I need? ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to convert a string to constant. Well it is easy. Read an example:

```
string = 'Hash'
const = Object.const_get(string) #=> Hash
const.new #=> {}; <- it is an empty Hash!
```

But be careful. If there's no such a constant you will get uninitialized constant error. In this case your adventures will stop.

I hope I understood your question and you will understand my answer.

Comment: He can use `Object.const_missing` for catching not-existent constants and use `Object.const_set` for setting that constant(if needed).

Answer (score 1):

How to change string to object, there are few options:

#### Bad(eval family):

```
eval("name_of_your_variable = #{21+21}")
eval("puts name_of_your_variable") #42
```

You can see that eval can make *everything*. So use with caution.

However, as pointed by @user2422869 you need(be in) *scope* - place where your variables are *saved*. So above code won't run everywhere

Everytime you run following method you create another scope

```
def meth1
  puts "defined: #{(defined? local_a) ? 'yes' : 'no'}!"
  eval 'local_a = 42'
  local_a += 100
  eval 'puts local_a'
end

meth1
```

and here is output:

> defined: no!
>   142

If you want to grab `local_a` from one of scopes of `meth1` you need binding.

```
def meth2
  var_a = 222
  binding
end

bin = meth2

bin.eval 'var_a'

#output:
#222
```

About binding you can read in [doc](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Binding.html). As for scopes, I don't have good site.

#### Better:

```
hash_variable = Hash.new # or just {}
hash[your_string_goes_here] = "some value #{42}"
puts hash[your_string_goes_here]
```

#### I don't know if good or bad:

As for this: `send "#{destiny}"`. I assume that your `destiny` doesn't exist, so you can use `method_missing`:

```
def method_missing arg, *args, &block
  #do some with "destiny"; save into variable/hash, check if "destiny" is in right place etc.
  # return something
end
```

Comment: Your "bad" variant doesn't work. You should add binding (or may be use instance variables instead of locals). And you may just write "= 42" not "= #{42}".

Comment: @user2422869 yes, it won't run because of scopes. I added some info. ps I wanted to show that he can use `#{}` in eval. I added this info as well. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you very much Darek. Although I do not understand this: hash[your_string_goes_here] = "some value #{42}"

Am I meant to match my old string with a new string? Why does #{42} stand for? Thank you :)

Comment: @gcarbonell *#{42}* -> I edited it. So, here, "#{21+21}" - it's interpolation of strings. Works in`" "` not in `' '`. Anything in `{}` is evaluated. So above string(`"#{21+21}"`) will be just "42". You can call any method, do computations(like +, -, * etc). `hash[key]=value` -> key might be your *destiny* and value might be your place where it can *go* from that place. Value might be array. Check http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Hash.html for examples of hash.